# Android alterar a cor de um botão por 1segundo

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile, interface

Tenho um Array que contem números inteiros de 0 a 4. 
{1,4,0,3,2} preciso que um botão pisque uma determinada cor de acordo com a sequência. Como isto é feito ?

Answer (score 1):

Achei interessante e resolvi escrever a maneira como resolveria essa questão.

> **NÃO FOI TESTADA** e carece de alguns ajustes, até porque alguns métodos que me pareceram mais óbvios não foram escritos, mas o grosso da logica está aqui.

Vamos lá.

Criar uma a variável ponteiro, qte_sequencia e um array para guardar as sequencias
  globais.

Criar um Handler que recebe as mensagens para alterar as cores do botões:

```
private Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 0:
                    volta_a_cor_normal;
                    if ( ponteiro < qte_sequencia )  {
                        ponteiro++;
                        AcendeCor(ponteiro);
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    seta_a_cor_vermelha;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    seta_a_cor_amarela;
                    break;
                case 15:
                    seta_a_cor_azul;
                    break;
                case 20:
                    seta_a_cor_verde;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Inicializa os objetos, atribuindo a cada um o evento do click para acender
  quando o jogador tocar no botão. Estou usando a classe DebouncedOnClickListener
  para evitar o duplo click, mas pode usar a que mais lhe convier.

```
 btn_vermelho = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVermelho);
 btn.setOnClickListener(new DebouncedOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDebouncedClick(View v) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
                    }
                     myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(5);
                     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                        public void run() {
                        myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                      } ,1000);
                   }
                });

...
```

repete para todos os outros alterando o que tiver de ser alterado.

Cria o procedimento que irá acender os botões automaticamente.

```
private void AcendeCor(Integer ponteiro) {
       Integer botao = sequencia[ ponteiro ];
       switch (botão} {
            1 :  {
                   SetaBotaoAmarelo;
                   break;
                 }
            2 :  {
                   SetaBotaoVermelho;
                   break;
                 }                       
            3 :  {
                   SetaBotaoVerde;
                   break;
                 }      
            4 :  {
                   SetaBotaoAzul;
                   break;
                 }      
       }                 
       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                        public void run() {
                        myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                      } ,1000);
                   }

    }
```

Digamos que vou gerar uma sequencia de 5 cores para o usuário repetir

A sequencia gerada aleatoriamente foi essa:

1,2,2,4,3

Zera a variável ponteiro e seta qte_sequencia = 5

Chamo o metodo `AcendeCor( ponteiro )`

O metodo recebe o ponteiro, verifica qual o botão que deve acender de acordo
    com a sequencia. Acende e inicializa o Handler.
    Esse por sua vez espera 1 segundo e chama o myHandler que apaga o botão, incrementa o ponteiro e repete o processo.

Comment: Olá Reginaldo, perdão pela demora em te responder. Usei sua solução e ela me ajudou a resolver o problema! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode setar a cor que quiser e depois usar um `handler` pra setar pra outra cor após 1 segundo:

```
Button btn_1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_1);

        btn_1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

        new Handler().postDelayed(() ->
                btn_1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)), 1000);
```